# MODX resourcealbum. Неверный адрес

Tags: modx, ресурсы

Добрый день.

В проекте использую resourcealbum для генерации галереи.

```
<section class="gallery [[+tv.gallery-extraclass]]">
    [[!getImageList?
        &tvname=`resourcealbum`
        &tpl=`@CODE:<img src="/[[+image]]" style="[[+id]]">`
        &docid=`[[+id]]`
    [[!Sort? &defsort=`id`]]
    ]]
</section>
```

Проблема в том, что при генерации ссылки на изображение подставляется неверная папка. А точней, подставляется id первого ресурса из списка.

Т.е. получается адрес вида: /assets/resourceimages/16/image.jpg
16 - это id первого ресурса из списка.

Я думал, что проблема в том, что неверно работает проход по ресурсам, однако [[+id]] в style выдает верный id текущего ресурса. + название изображения подставляется верное, не изменяется только папка (id ресурса)

Что может влиять на то, что не изменяется папка?

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы оказалось довольно простым:

В источниках файлов (Медиа - источники файлов) жмем редактировать источник ResourceMediaPath.
Далее просто добавляем ! в baseUrl:
[[!migxResourceMediaPath? &pathTpl=`assets/resourceimages/{id}/` &createFolder=`1`]]

Готово.